# Calculus series homework

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a following series:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1!+2!+...+n!}{(2n)!}$$
Now I'm supposed to check if it diverges or converges. 
I'm using the ratio test to see if it diverges or converges anbsolutely:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{1!+2!+...+n!+(n+1)!}{(2(n+1))!} \div \frac{1!+2!+...+n!}{(2n)!} \right|&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|
\frac{(1!+2!+...+n!+(n+1)!)(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!(1!+2!+...+n!)}\right| \\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{(n+1)!(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\right|\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right|\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{n!}{n+2}\right|\\
&=&\infty\\
\end{eqnarray*}
As $\infty > 1$, I can conclude that the series diverges absolutely. Because the $a_n$ is always positive, I can also say that the original series diverges.

Is this corret? Should I add anything else?

Comment: Before you use a "Test" find out how the thing is going to $0$, by looking at it. The bottom is, for $n$ of any size, like $10$, hugely bigger than the top.

Comment: Be very careful about that "cancellation" you're doing when going from the first line to the second. We can only "cancel" *factors*. If you could actually do what you're claiming, then for example, $$\frac{11}3=\frac{33}9=\frac{1!+2!+3!+4!}{1!+2!+3!}=4!=24,$$ which is patently not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off with the comparison test. Observe that
$$
1!+2!+\dots+n!\le n\,n!.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have several serious algebra errors.

1. $\frac{1!+2!+\cdots+n!+(n+1)!}{1!+2!+\cdots+n!}\neq (n+1)!$.
2. $\frac{(2n!)}{(2n+2)!}\neq \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$.  In fact it equals $\frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\dfrac{1!+2!+...+n!}{(2n)!}<\dfrac{n\cdot{n!}}{n!\cdot(n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}=\dfrac{n}{(n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}$$